# SharePoint Form Based Authentication

Tags: forms-authentication

I have created a form based sharepoint website for external user which has MS-SQL as it's back-end . Now i want to design a custom login page where i can give them options of signing up , forget password and login . So my question is how can i create a custom login page and also the registration page and link it simultaneously to the MS SQL .

Answer (score 0):

I found an article on Technet with instructions to configure form-based authentication on SharePoint:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Once I have customized default login page of FBA and wrote an article on it

[image]

[Branding Default Login Page for Form Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991205/Branding-Default-Login-Page-for-Form-Based-Authent)

For managing user: add, delete, change password

[SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/)